NextJS 15 default starter app show an error
using npx create-next-app@latest i got an error on a fresh start using NextJS 15. i already update my node version. any work around with this or should i just use NextJS previous Version?
the fresh app from NextJS 15

the error i get

updating my node version, knowing about the invalid html placement. or i miss something during installation of NextJS 15?

Maybe there is stale build info - could you stop your next server, delete the .next directory, then see if you get the same error?

okay, i did that but still the same error

This happens because your are using ColorZilla Chrome Extension. It adds an attribute to HTML after it has been rendedred called cz-shortcut-listen:"true". This cause hydration error in NextJS.
To fix this make sure you disable ColorZilla Chrome Extension on your browser.

i do in fact use the Colorzilla extension in firefox browser, now the problem is fix. didn't know till today that the extension can cause such problem. thanks
